# Using C# and Powershell, how to set 'Manager' for mailbox created on Exchange server 2010

Tags: c#, powershell

I am using the below code to connect to a exchange server remotely and create a mailbox in Exchange server 2010.

```
public class Exchange2010
{
    public string strAccountName;
    public string strAccountPwd;
    public string strExchange2010PSURI;
    public string strAccountSufix;

    private string dirPathADStafftest;
    private string dirPathADStafftestUsr;
    private string dirPathADStafftestpwdUsr;

    public Exchange2010()
    {
        strAccountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountName"];
        strAccountPwd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountPwd"];
        strExchange2010PSURI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Exchange2010PSURI"];
        strAccountSufix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountName"].Substring(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountName"].IndexOf("@") + 1);

        dirPathADStafftest = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathAD"];
        dirPathADStafftestUsr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathADUser"];
        dirPathADStafftestpwdUsr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathADPwd"];
    }

    public Boolean AddMailbox(string mailboxName, string displayName, string alias, string password)
    {
        Command psCmd = new Command("New-Mailbox");
        var secure_password = new SecureString();

        foreach (char c in password)
            secure_password.AppendChar(c);

        mailboxName = mailboxName.Replace(" ", "");

        psCmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Name", mailboxName));
        psCmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("DisplayName", displayName));
        psCmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Password", secure_password));
        psCmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Alias", alias));
        psCmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("PrimarySmtpAddress", mailboxName + "@xxx.edu.au"));
        psCmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("UserPrincipalName", mailboxName + "@xxx.edu.au"));

        Collection<PSObject> psExecResult = fnGetPSData(psCmd, null);

        if (psExecResult.Count == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    Private Collection<PSObject> fnGetPSData(Command psCmd1, Command psCmd2)
    {
        Pipeline psPipeLine = null;
        Runspace psRunSpace = null;
        var varSecurePwd = new SecureString();
        try
        {
            foreach (var c in strAccountPwd)
            {
                varSecurePwd.AppendChar(c);
            }
            PSCredential psCreds = new PSCredential(strAccountName, varSecurePwd);
            WSManConnectionInfo psConnInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(strExchange2010PSURI), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", psCreds);
            psConnInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
            psRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(psConnInfo);

            psRunSpace.Open();
            psPipeLine = psRunSpace.CreatePipeline();

            if (psCmd1 != null)
            {
                psPipeLine.Commands.Add(psCmd1);
            }
            if (psCmd2 != null)
            {
                psPipeLine.Commands.Add(psCmd2);
            }
            Collection<PSObject> psObjects = psPipeLine.Invoke();

            return psObjects;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (psPipeLine != null && psPipeLine.Commands != null)
            {
                psPipeLine.Commands.Clear();
                psPipeLine.Dispose();
            }

            if (psRunSpace != null)
            {
                psRunSpace.Close();
                psRunSpace.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly and the mailbox get created.

Now I want to set the Manager field in Organization tab for the mailbox through this code. Is there a way to achieve it? [Manager field in Organization tab - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dge8I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the user that you desire to be the created user's manager, get its `distinguishedName` attrubute and set `manager` attribute of the user being created to that value. You don't need Exchange server side to achieve the effect.

```
$user=get-aduser "New user" # or create
$manager=get-aduser "Manager"
$user.manager = $manager.DistinguishedName
set-aduser -instance $user
```